# Are symmetric binary matrices necessarily positive semi-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with entries only 0 or 1 and the diagonal entries of $A$ are all 1. Is A positive (semi-) definite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Its all eigenvalues are 1

Comment: @Shailesh No, they aren't. But you don't really need the eigenvalues: what about calculating the matrix principal minors?

Comment: The trace is $3$, the determinant is $-1$.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake in calculation.